# C/C++ for loop with existing start value

Tags: c++, c, variables, for-loop

Here's a C/C++ for loop:

```
int i;
for (i = myVar; i != someCondition(); i++)
  doSomething();
// i is now myVar plus the number of iterations until someCondition
```

I recently had to use a loop like this. I needed to keep the value of `i` because I wanted to know what `i` was when the return value of `someCondition()` became true. And the start value of `i` was `myVar` which had no further reason of existing. So what *wanted* to do was:

```
for (myVar; myVar != someCondition(); myVar++)
  doSomething();
// myVar is now myVar + the number of iterations.
```

This made a lot more sense to me. I didn't see why I had to use a whole new variable when `myVar` was just what I needed. But this is not valid code. Is there a way around creating a whole new variable for this situation?

Comment: Just leave the `init` part of `for (init;condition;step)` empty: `for( ; condition ; step)`. (Of course this assumes that `myVar` is declared some place before the loop.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is,

```
for( ; myVar != someCondition(); myVar++)
       doSomething();
```

But you statement about the following loop being incorrect is wrong,

```
for (myVar; myVar != someCondition(); myVar++)
  doSomething();
```

The above code will also work fine in C.

Comment: However there probably will be a warning about an expression without side effects.

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wunused-value`

Comment: Agreed :). What I tried to point out was that the statement will not give a compilation error as the OP has mentioned.

Comment: Yes I agree, it's legal and there will be no error, just a warning.  Unless the OP is using `-Werror`, then warnings will stop compilation just like errors.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're after:

```
for ( ; myVar != someCondition(); myVar++)
    doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that a `while` loop more closely resembles your intentions. Indeed, you are doing something `while` `someCondition()` is `true`, and increasing `myVar` is a side effect.

```
while(myvar != someCondition()) {
 doSomething();
 myVar++;
}
```

To be clear: the statements are equivalent. I am just advocating for what I believe to be more idiomatic code.

You could even use a `do`/`while` loop, but it somewhat does not feel idiomatic to me. Below you will find three examples; they all do the same, but *feel* different. Take your pick!

```
#include<iostream>

int someCondition() {
  return 10;
}

void doSomething(int myVar) {
  std::cout<<"... I'm doing something with myVar = "<<myVar<<std::endl;
}

int using_for() {
  int myVar = 7;
  for( ; myVar!=someCondition(); myVar++) {
    doSomething(myVar);
  }
  return myVar;
}

int using_while() {
  int myVar = 7;
  while(myVar != someCondition()) {
    doSomething(myVar);
    myVar++;
  }
  return myVar;
}

int using_do() {
  int myVar = 7;
  do {
    doSomething(myVar);
  } while(++myVar != someCondition());
  return myVar;

}

int main() {
  std::cout<<"using for: "<<using_for()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"using while: "<<using_while()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"using do/while: "<<using_do()<<std::endl;

}
```

Output:

```
... I'm doing something with myVar = 7
... I'm doing something with myVar = 8
... I'm doing something with myVar = 9
using for: 10
... I'm doing something with myVar = 7
... I'm doing something with myVar = 8
... I'm doing something with myVar = 9
using while: 10
... I'm doing something with myVar = 7
... I'm doing something with myVar = 8
... I'm doing something with myVar = 9
using do/while: 10
```